# Find sufficent condition for $g(y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, extreme-value-theorem

Let $x_0$ and $y_0$ - stationary points of twice differentiable functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$.

And $f(x_0)=0$.

Find sufficent condition for $g(y)$ so that function $z(x,y)=f^2(x)\cdot g(y)$ has an extremum at the point $(x_0,y_0)$.

---

First I found necessary condition -    $z^{'}_x=2f(x)f^{'}(x)g(y)=0$ ; $z^{'}_y=f^2(x)g^{'}(y)=0$.

Both conditions are met at point $(x_0,y_0)$.

Sufficent condition - $\Delta =\begin{vmatrix}
z^{''}_{xx} &z^{''}_{xy} \\ 
 z^{''}_{yx}& z^{''}_{yy}
\end{vmatrix}> 0$ . But $\Delta =0$...